# Spring transaction not being created when invoking @Transactional method via reflection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, reflection, spring-data-jpa

I have a class that is invoking a public method on another class via reflection. The invoking class already has an active transaction, and the public method on the invoked class is marked with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void handleProcess() { ..}
```

The invocation looks like

```
Runnable runnable = null;
Method handleMethod = config.handleProcessMethod;
            Object handler = autowireHandler(process);
            runnable = () -> {
                LOGGER.info("executing method {} on {}",handleMethod,handler);
                handleMethod.invoke(handler);
            };
runnable.run();
```

The method is called correctly, but the log indicates that it is particpating in the current transaction instead of creating a new one.

```
08:54:33.452 [process-executor-2] DEBUG o.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager ... for JPA transaction
08:54:33.453 [process-executor-2] DEBUG o.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
```

**Edit: Actually the logs from above are being created *within* the invoked method, caused by a JPA repository, not prior to it. So it looks like the @Transactional annotation isn't being processed at all.**

Is the reflection causing spring to miss the @Transactional annotation? I need the invoked method to use it's own transaction so that it's committed prior to returning from the invocation.

Comment: Where does the method you invoke using reflection come from? Are you sure it is the method of a Spring bean?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I am autowiring the bean manually using the spring context, but I guess that doesn't mean spring knows anything about the @Transactional? 

How would one go about getting spring to handle @Transactional on a manually autowired bean?

Comment: If you use Spring's bean it should respect `@Transactional`. Could you post more code? It is hard to predict what went wrong with just this snippet.

Comment: Since you don't pass your `Runnable` to a `Thread(Executor)` and instead call `run()` manually, the `Runnable` is not invoked in a separate Thread, but instead in the same Thread as the caller.

Comment: Actually the runnable is called in a separate Executor, but I condensed it for the above example. I realize that a full code example is preferable but unfortunately I'm unable to post it here. If synchronous vs async is believed to be a source of the issue then I can test it, but as of right now it seems that the reflection is the culprit.

Comment: @NathanHughes That sounds like a possible explanation. So is there no way to get this reflection to work with spring proxies?

Comment: @NathanHughes I can't use spring async methods. The specification of which class and method to invoke is dynamic and determined at runtime by user configuration and other classpath resources.

Comment: @NathanHughes I read somewhere that spring has its own reflection logic, but didn't know any details. I'll continue chasing it down.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation tells Spring what to wrap with a proxy that implements the transactional behavior. Reflection is bypassing that proxy and calling the wrapped method directly. Looking at the logs should confirm that, you may need to dial up log level for spring stuff.

Don't use reflection for this, because that's going behind Spring's back and it can't help you. You can autowire a list of services that implement a common interface. Your code can go through the list and figure out which one is relevant to what you need to do, then call the method on the chosen service.

If you are submitting tasks to an executor, you are going to have trouble when there is no entitymanager found on the worker thread. If you make these services use Spring async methods instead, that will let Spring handle the transactions, entityManager, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work with the current codebase. The determination of which method to invoke is based on an annotation which is part of the API we built. The user annotates a method and that method is what gets called here. We can't/don't force the user to implement an interface because our API doesn't really know what the user is doing, it just knows that this method is what needs to be called at this point in time. But I see why that very same disconnect is what breaks the Spring @Transactional logic.